# How to send Private data class's member function as a callback for a thread in c++ unmanaged?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, timer, unmanaged

I have some unamanged code I ported into VC100. I am trying to run a member function at a intervalms using a timer. This class is using the design pattern Private class data. I am unsure how to set the call back. I have tried

```
    class IProcessable {
    public:
        virtual void process() throw () = 0;

    protected:
        IProcessable() throw () {}
        virtual ~IProcessable() throw () {}
    };
```

---

```
class Processor::Private {
    private:
        IProcessable & mProcessable;
    public:
        Private(IProcessable & processable,
            unsigned int   interval_ms) throw () : 
            mProcessable(processable)
        {
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(this->callTimer), 0, 0, NULL);
            // I want to send the callTimer to be called at the interval..
            onTimer();
        }

        __fastcall ~Private() throw () {
        }
        void callTimer()
        {
            mProcessable.process();
        }
    private:
        void __fastcall onTimer() {
            mProcessable.process();
        }

    };

    Processor::Processor(IProcessable & processable, unsigned int interval_ms) throw () :
        mPrivate(new Private(processable, interval_ms)) {}

    Processor::~Processor() throw () {
        delete mPrivate;
    } 
}
```

error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'

Comment: If you're using vc100, use `noexcept` instead of `throw ()`.

Answer (score 0):

`callTimer` is a *member* function, it needs a `this` context to know which instance of the class it is operating on.

`LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` requires a function that takes an LPVOID (void*) parameter and returns a DWORD, `callTimer` takes no arguments and has no return.

What you need is a trampoline static function that takes a class instance and forwards to the appropriate member function:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(this->callTimerIf), (void*)this, 0, NULL);
```

and (this is a member of Private):

```
static DWORD callTimerIf(void* instance)
{
    Private* pvt = (Processor::Private*)instance;
    pvt->callTimer();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`callTimer` is a class method. It has a hidden `this` parameter, so it looks to the C works ad if you are passing a function that looks something like

```
void (*) (Processor * this)
```

and not

```
DWORD (*) (LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
```

So what you need to do is something like this:

```
class Processor::Private {
    private:
        IProcessable & mProcessable;
    public:
        Private(IProcessable & processable,
            unsigned int   interval_ms) throw () : 
            mProcessable(processable)
        {
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(&callTimer), this, 0, NULL);
            onTimer();
        }

        __fastcall ~Private() throw () {
        }
        static DWORD callTimer(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
        {
            Private * priv = (Private *)lpThreadParameter;
            priv->mProcessable.process();
            return 0; // or whatever makes sense
        }
    private:
        void __fastcall onTimer() {
            mProcessable.process();
        }

    };
```

Important change 1:

```
static DWORD callTimer(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
```

The `callTimer` method is now static and requires no object to be invoked. So there is no `this` parameter. Instead `this` is hidden away as `lpThreadParameter` and cast to a `Private *` to call the function we really want called. It also matches the prototype required by `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`.

Important Change 2:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(&callTimer), this, 0, NULL);
```

passin the address of the now-static `callTimer` method and `this` as the `lpParameter` that will show up again later as `lpThreadParameter`.

Getting the timing right is another question, but if you are going with this architecture you probably want a [Waitable Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012(v=vs.85).aspx).

Other approaches still use the Waitable Timer, but use it through [Overlapped IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx) and may help you make your program easier to synchronize.